# Aligning common array elements together in the same index

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Given this input:

```
[
    ['a', 'b', 'c']
    ['b', 'c', 'd']
    ['a', 'd', 'b']
]
```

I'd like to return this output:

```
[
    ['a',  'b', 'c']
    [null, 'b', 'c',  'd']
    ['a',  'b', null, 'd']
]
```

Such that each matching string in each array is in the same position in the array, and any gaps are null values.

**Context**

[image]

I need to render a bunch of arbitrary strings like above, but ensure that each common string between the columns are rendered on the same horizontal line. In this example, each array is a column in the above image. Once I have the underlying array set up correctly, I can just use simple loops to render the strings in the correct position.

Comment: does the order of the elements matter?

Comment: Is the largest possible array size known?

Comment: An interesting question.  What have you tried in order to solve it?

Comment: Would it be a problem to have a `null` at the end of the first row for consistency?

Comment: @JayJordan yes the largest possible array size can be computed beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce()` method and one ES6 `Set` to keep current values.

```js
const input = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['b', 'c', 'd'],['a', 'd', 'b']]

const all = new Set
const result = input.reduce((r, arr) => {
  arr.forEach(e => all.add(e))
  r.push([...all].sort().map(e => arr.includes(e) ? e : null))
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Note that this would turn `[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'e'], ['a', 'd', 'b']]` into the somewhat bizarre `[['a', 'b', 'c'], [null, 'b', 'c', 'e'], ['a', 'b', null, 'd', null]]`

Comment: I think that is what it should return.

Comment: But that aligns the `d` from the third input row with the `e` from the second one.  I don't know for sure, but I would expect that to be an issue.

Comment: I think that just removing sort will fix that if that is the issue https://jsfiddle.net/7urmjm7e/3/

Comment: Yes, that works, so long as you don't need it sorted.  A nice solution.  The ideas overlap my solution, but they have very different feels.

Answer (score 1):

This version includes a `null` at any place it might be applicable, including at the end of the first row.

```js
const transform = (orig) => {
  const template = Array.from(new Set(orig.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b))))
  return orig.map(row => row.slice(0).reduce( // `slice` to avoid mutating original
    (output, val) => {
      const idx = template.indexOf(val)
      output[idx] = val
      return output
    } , Array(template.length).fill(null)
  ))
}

const orig = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'd', 'b']]

console.log(transform(orig))
```

If you want your values sorted, you could just add a `sort` invocation at the end of the first line:

```
   const template = Array.from(new Set(orig.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)))).sort()
```

As it is, they are sorted by when the values are first seen.

The template is just the result of taking the unique values from the concatenation of all the rows, in this case, `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, and it serves to tell the remainder of the code where in each row to place the given value.

You could always `map` over the rows again to remove any trailing `null`s, but if they're not a problem, I don't think it would be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(let i = 0; i < table[0].length; i++) {
   const match = table[0][i];
   for(const row of table.slice(1)) {
     if(row[i] !== match) {
       row.splice(i, 0, null);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Third row of this is `["a", null, null, "d", "b"]` instead of expected `['a',  'b', null, 'd']`

Answer (score 0):

Create an 'intermediate' array that contains all the possible values, and from there the path is quite simple:

```js
var Array = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'd', 'b']];

var TempArray = [];
var EndArray = [];

Array.forEach(function(a) {
  a.sort();
  a.forEach(function(b) {
  
    if (!TempArray.includes(b)) {
    
      TempArray.push(b);
    }
  });
});

TempArray.sort();
Array.forEach(function(a) {

  a.sort();
  var Member = [];
  TempArray.forEach(function(b) {
  
    Member.push((a.includes(b)) ? b : null);
    
  });
  EndArray.push(Member);
});

console.log(EndArray);
```